# How to restrict trailing whitespace in model mvc

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc, model

I have an registration form which has First name and last name as one of the model property. I dont want the user to enter white spaces at start and end of the string. I want to achieve this using Regex. I tried following code,but this doesn't allow user to enter white space between two words, which i doesn't want to restrict.

```
[RegularExpression(@"^[^\s]+$", ErrorMessage = "Required.")]
```

Valid: `"John Paul"`

Invalid: `" John Paul"`

Invalid: `"John Paul "`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To allow one or two words, use

```
@"^\S+(?:\s+\S+)?$"
```

where `(?:\s+\S+)?` matches an *optional* 1+ non-whitespace symbol sequence (`\S+`) after 1+ whitespace symbols (`\s+`).

To allow  1 or more "words", use

```
@"^\S+(?:\s+\S+)*$"
```

**NOTE**: To only allow 1 whitespace between the words, replace `\s+` with `\s`.

**NOTE2**: If you want to only allow *regular spaces* (i.e. no tabs, etc.) replace `\s` with a space.

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `\S+` - 1 or more non-whitespace chars
- `(?:\s+\S+)*` - a non-capturing group matching 0+ (due to `*` quantifier) sequences of:

  - `\s+` -  1+ (due to `+` quantifier, remove it if you need to only allow single whitespace between words) whitespaces
  - `\S+` - 1 or more non-whitespace chars
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: @"^\S+\s+\S+$" this one requires two words any how, which is not my case.@"^\S+(?:\s+\S+)*$" this worked for me. Thanks :)

Comment: @AkshayChawla: Ah, I forgot to make the second one optional. However, to match 1 or more (no maximum threshold) use the second regex, yes.

Comment: i tried finding an article where i can understand all this regex, but couldn't find. so can you share any article from where i can develop my regex skills. :)

Comment: There are many. If you plan to work with .NET regex, surely you should read [MSDN Regex Quick Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx). However, to grasp the basics, do the exercises at http://regexone.com and refer to http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html.